# how to translate the text in pdf to required language in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-translate

I am using windows.print() to generate print the current document. my required use case is that I need to extract all the text from the current document and translate it to the required language and then do windows.print(). My code is in js. How can I solve this any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to write your own translator? Are you asking how to translate from one language to another with JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

#### Let's break down your question in pieces

1. The translation part. Please give it a try ** Google Translate**

   ````
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en-US">
   <body>

   <h1>My Web Page</h1>

   <p>Hello everybody!</p>

   <p>Translate this page:</p>

   <div id="google_translate_element"></div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   function googleTranslateElementInit() {
     new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
   }
   </script>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

   <p>You can translate the content of this page by selecting a language in the select box.</p>

   </body>
   </html>```
   ````
2. Part 2 `windows.print()`
   => As I understand, you need to print the document to PDF after the page translation (That's answer itself)